# is there a program that can backup DVDs to ISO without needing to change the DVD Region of the OS

Tags: windows-7, backup, dvd, iso-image

i was backing up up my Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion DVDs to ISO using DVD Shrink however i brought the Limited Editions from the US (it came with the Manga), in the past i've normally backup Region 4 (Australia) DVDs so when i went to use my US DVDs i was asked to change the region which i learned i only had a set number of changes (think it was 5), luckly DVD Shrink will turn the ISO of the DVD to Region 0 afterwards

Now i get DVDs from Local Australian Distributors, UK Distributors and US Distributors in that priority, Limited/Collector Editions trumps that and i would like to backup all my DVDs incase of a fire and i loose the originals i can burn the backups on DVD RW when i want to watch them again however i can't predict where i would get a DVD from

one solution would be to have 3 Computers and use each one however at the moment i only have 1 computer and a Laptop, so i am wondering if there is a program which will allow me to back up my DVD without having to change the Region Setting of my DVD Drive

Comment: Have you tried using [DVD Decrypter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Decrypter)? (commenting this in regards to the community's input)

Comment: Look for a "ripper" which has "de-css" support.  de-css support is quite common, and basically allows you to handle a DVD without caring what region you are on.  Also, look for a cheap DVD drive which you can set to "region free" which will allow you to watch DVDs from any region.